# Having to run rake assets:precompile to update template changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I recently pushed a production branch to Heroku and had to do a `rake:assets precompile`

Now - If I make *any* static changes to *any* of my templates, none of them will update. I have to constantly run rake assets:precompile from the terminal in order to update any of my views.

Is there a fix for this nonsense?

Comment: Did you commit the compiled assets to your repo? If they're already generated and provided by your git push then Heroku will not generate them for you. If this is the case, just delete the precompiled assets from your repo.

Answer (score 0):

In /config/environments/production.rb you need to set:

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

Then push to Heroku and you should be set.